# How can I find the IP address of my AWS Route 53 nameserver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, hosting

Apparently there is a special requirement of .nl domains that necessitates the disclosure of nameserver IP addresses. I am trying to host a static website out of my AWS bucket on GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already!
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3ans-30.awsdns-03.com&run=toolpage#

the supertool of mxtoolbox reveals the IP addresses of nameserver.

Comment: You can also use standard system utilities like `dig` and `nslookup`.